# How to speed up form load and form closing

Tags: c#

I have developed an application. It is working well but form loading is slow. And form closing also have the same issues. What are the approaches available for increasing the speed?

```
Form3 child = new Form3(); // Create new instance of form.
child.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(child_FormClosed); 
child.Show(); // Show child.
this.Hide(); // Hide parent.
```

This is the method i used to direct main interface to sub interfaces.

Comment: That will greatly depend on what you are doing in the load and close event handlers

Comment: This is far too vague to help you

Comment: *also have some problem* ... what is this problem? could edit into your question?

Comment: Lots and lots of controls or long running queries would cause this.

Comment: You need to tell us what is on the form, before anyone can give a targetted answer.

Answer (score 4):

The best answer to your codeless question is to use asynchronous load-up and unload of form's resources.

The delay in closing and opening is happened because your code is running in UI-thread, loads all resources and only after that the form is shown.